# how can I add the partial scores of each individual part to the final table under the row of question 2?

Tags: tables, exam

how can I add the partial scores of each individual part to the final table under the row of question 2?

I would like a table like this one:

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\usepackage[italian]{babel}  

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\ExamResetAfterFirstRun}{%
  \renewcommand*{\PgInfo@write}[1]{}%
  \renewcommand*{\label}[1]{\@bsphack\@esphack}%
}
\makeatother

\pointpoints{Punto}{Punti}
\bonuspointpoints{punto (bonus)}{punti (bonus)}






\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
      \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
      #2
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}




\begin{document}

\large 



\newcounter{copynum} % copy number, to be printed in the footer 
\newcounter{NumCopy} % how many copies do we want?
\setcounter{NumCopy}{1} % we want 3
\whiledo{\thecopynum<\theNumCopy}{%
  \setcounter{page}{1} % start numbering pages for the current copy at 1
  \addtocounter{copynum}{1} % the number of the current copy
  \setcounter{question}{1} % make questions start at 1 again
  \setcounter{part}{1}  % make parts start at 1 again
  \setcounter{numquestions}{0}
  \setcounter{numpoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numbonuspoints}{0}
  \setcounter{numparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubparts}{0}
  \setcounter{numsubsubparts}{0}
  \ifnum\value{copynum}>1 %
    \ExamResetAfterFirstRun
  \fi






 \begin{questions}



\question[3] question 

\question questions: 

\begin{parts}
\part[3]
bla bla
\part[3]
bla bla


\end{parts}


\end{questions}  





{ %\small
 { 
  \begin{center}
  \hqword{exercise}
  \hpword{points}
  \bhpword{Bonus Points:}
  \htword{\textbf{Tot}}
  \hsword{total points}
  \cellwidth{1.0em}
  \gradetable[h][questions]
  \end{center}
  \begin{center}
  \end{center}}
  }





}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Can you please cut this down to a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228)? That is, the code should compile and be as *small* as possible to demonstrate your problem. It's much easier to help if we can see your problem immediately and not have to sift through a lot of irrelevant code first.

Comment: I've modified my code and I added a picture of my idea of table.

Comment: What you ask, cannot be done. The exam class doesn't keep points of parts, subparts or subsubparts. Only the total points of the question is kept.